# Trying to run imagen-pytorch

Tags: python, github, pytorch, computer-vision, setup.py

I'm trying to run this "imagen-pytorch" repo https://github.com/lucidrains/imagen-pytorch/blob/main/README.md

I've cloned it and tried running the setup.py file on pycharm (CE) however I get the following error:

```
$ python setup.py             
usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
   or: setup.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
   or: setup.py --help-commands
   or: setup.py cmd --help
```

There are no further instructions on the README.md file. Please can you explain where I am going wrong?

Comment: you have to run with some command - ie, `python setup.py build` , `python setup.py install`. Maybe first run `python setup.py --help-commands`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to run with some command.

The most popular are

```
python setup.py build 
python setup.py install
```

You need them to install module.

---

You can see other commands using

```
python setup.py --help-commands
```

---

Maybe they forgot to show this information because other modules on GitHub already show it ;)